# How to find the corresponding Enum constructor value of a given value in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, enums

Below given is my enum class

```
enum class Letters(val display:String){
a("A"),
b("B"),
c("C")
}
```

Suppose I am getting the value 'a' as a result from an external function. How can I map it with the above enum to get the display value as "A" ?

Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kotlin safe conversion from string to enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51663446/kotlin-safe-conversion-from-string-to-enum)

Answer (score 0):

```
val extResult = "a"
val letter = Letters.values().find { it.display.equals(extResult, ignoreCase = true) }
```

Comment: I solved it this way --  Letters.valueOf("a").display

Answer (score -1):

```
fun main(){
   Letters.values{println(a)}
}
```

I think it will work

Answer (score -1):

```
a.display
```

And that's it if I unserstood your question correctly.